# SSl Handshake_failure SOAPUI

Tags: batch-file, ssl, https, soapui, sslhandshakeexception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

i am using a Rest Service in soapui. i have to run it using test runner bat file in command prompt, but while doing so it is giving the above mentioned error.

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2
```

i have tried editing my VM options file with this.I have no permission to edit my test runner Bat file nor i can do so. So can anyone suggest a solution to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the SSL cipher of the REST server doesn't support java!

Use https://www.ssllabs.com/ to check if your REST API supports java,
[check this image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEaes.png)

If it shows like this, you can download the files from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html. Once done, replace the two JARs (local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar) under your JRE's lib/security directory with the ones from the downloaded package.

If not, please provide more detail information so we can check in detail.

Comment: thankyou so much , i will implement this and let u know in case of any query